# Anonymous users denied access to XSL stylesheet

Tags: permissions, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a XSLTListViewWebPart on a page and it is linked to an XSL stylesheet located in the Style Library. Anonymous users have read access to the Style Library. When a logged in user views the page, the XSLTListViewWebPart works fine. However, when an anonymous user views the page the XSLTListViewWebPart gives the following error message:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

This seems to be a permission issue, but anonymous users should already be able to access the XSL stylesheet.

Comment: Can you access the site as the anonymous user and try putting the path to the style sheet in the browser address bar? Then, you can verify if the xslt file is the problem or if it is some other resource.

Comment: @Laurie When I tried that as anonymous user, I was able to download the actual xsl file.

Comment: I should add, the XSLTListViewWebPart works fine with anonymous users when I use the OOB stylesheet. When I link the stylesheet in the style library it breaks. The one in the style library is just slightly tweaked version of the OOB stylesheet.

Comment: Can you use FireBug and take a look at the Net tab? You may see a GET that causes the error.

Comment: If I recall it correctly, inside the xslt there are references to other xslt file. You may have a permission issue with those?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt This issue seems to be a Sharepoint bug. Look at this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepoint2010customization/thread/3d95f279-91c0-47be-b7b9-3a0f83ff4f8c

Answer (score 1):

Try the DataFormWebpart, can do the same, and works fine for anonymous users.
In Sharepoint Designer insert empty data view, choose data source ...

Answer (score 1):

One Possible option is to add xsl inline in xsltListViewWebPart. See this blog here -

http://www.manvir.net/how-to-add-xsltlistview-webpart-to-sharepoint-publishing-page

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and managed to resolve it using this solution

I hope this helps someone

[Sharepoint 2010 XsltListViewWebPart on site definition template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42783/sharepoint-2010-xsltlistviewwebpart-on-site-definition-template)

Thanks

Nicholas